# Cannot print data from MySQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a PHP script that is supposed to interact with a MySQL database. On my local testing server, the code echos out what it is supposed to just fine, but in the live environment, I get an error saying `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in [file path removed for security] on line 42`. Here is my code from around line 42.

```
$query = "SELECT " . $data . " FROM mySchemaTable WHERE incrementId = " . $something;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH); // This line is 42.
echo $row['0'];
break;
```

Comment: is the row actually named '0'?  Because that's what you're asking for.  Try $row[0];

Comment: your query failed and you failed to check for failure: `$result = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`.

Comment: What exactly is in `$data` at this point in the code?

Comment: This error is telling you that there is something wrong with your query....has nothing to do with the `$row['0']`

Comment: @A.O. the `$row['0'] ` is caused by using `MYSQL_BOT` in `fetch_array` function ,returns a indexed array and numeric indexed too

Comment: @GregoryBallantine At this point in the code, `$data` holds the name of one of the columns.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Most likely, the column name in `$data` is a reserved word and you need to put backticks around it, or `$something` is not set correctly. If you show us the error message from `mysqli_error()` we may be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Also, what does `echo $query` show?

Comment: What about your `$conn` ? Did you use `mysqli_connect` or `new mysqli` ?

Comment: @iamsleepy If the problme were with `$conn` he would have gotten an error on the previous line.

Comment: Yes @Barmar, but I am suspecting that he used procedural mysqli but calling `fetch` like it was an object.

Comment: @ThiagoFrança yes I know that, but unless his column is named '0', it should be `$row[0]` or `$row['columnName']` NOT `$row['0']`

Comment: @iamsleepy It doesn't matter whether he uses procedural or OO syntax, I think he would still get an error if he called `mysqli_query()` with an invalid `$conn`.

Comment: @A.O. `$row[0]` and `$row['0']` are equivalent, try it and see.

Comment: When you took this from your local testing server to the remote server, did you change the database connection credentials?

Comment: @DavidB I'm voting to close this question. Without seeing the expanded query and the SQL error message, there's no way to advise on how to fix the problem.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few problems with your code:

Firstly, you're mixing OOP and Procedural programming with MySQLi commands. Although PHP allows this, you'll want to make that uniform throughout. If you're using `$conn = mysqli_connect(parameters here);` you'll want to focus on procedural (change `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)` to `mysqli_fetch_array($conn, MYSQLI_BOTH);` for instance). (I would assume you're doing this, so do this ^ change)

Else, if it's `$conn = new mysqli(parameters);` then you'll want to make it OOP based; instead of `mysqli_query($sql);` you'd use `$conn->query($sql);`, assuming $sql contains the query you want to run.

Secondly, `echo $row['0'];` should be `echo $row[0];` unless the row you're returning is actually named 0, in which case disregard this.

Thirdly, and as a side note, it's a bad idea to directly insert variables into SQL queries, especially if they're user generated.  You should look into sanitizing input or prepared statements to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Sanitizing Input Reference: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323)

Prepared Statements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: There's no requirement to be consistent in the use of OO and Procedural programming. It might be confusing to readers, but PHP itself has no problem with it.

Comment: I just tried `$array = array(1); echo $array['0'];` and it printed `1`. So PHP automatically converts this as necessary.

Comment: Protecting against SQL injection is certainly a good idea, but it won't necessarily solve whatever problem he's having. Note also that you can't use a placeholder when you're substituting a column name in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: That's my bad, I just edited to fix that, I didn't think you could mix the styles. And I mentioned the SQL injection stuff as a side note, so I know that won't fix it, but it's always good practice to protect against.

Comment: The error he's getting indicates that `mysqli_query()` is returning `false`, which means there's an error in the SQL. Which part of your answer solves that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved without my intervention. It turns out that my code was fine as it was, but something was wrong with my host's MySQL. It's fixed now, and everything is working again.